# "System.NotSupportedException: Unknown Jasmine version" error when running tests

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jasmine, resharper

When trying to run Jasmine tests in VS with ReSharper, I get the following error:

```
2018.04.05 10:45:53.850   ERROR System.NotSupportedException: Unknown Jasmine version '2.6' is selected.    at
JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestProvider.JavaScript.JavaScriptServiceProviderBase.GetRunStrategy(Boolean isTs, String defaultFrameworkVersion)    at
JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestProvider.JavaScript.Jasmine.JasmineTestElementBase.GetRunStrategy(IHostProvider hostProvider)    at
JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Launch.Stages.BuildStage.CollectProjectsToBuild() at
JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Launch.Stages.BuildStage.Run(CancellationToken token)    at
JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Launch.UnitTestLaunch.RunStage(Object stageObject)
```

What is likely to be causing this?

**Update**
If I install Jasmine 2.5.1 and set my ReSharper options to use version 2.5, it works.  Previously I was using 2.6.4 and Resharper set to Latest Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I got it working: Install Jasmine 2.5.1 and set my ReSharper options to use version 2.5, it works. Previously I was using 2.6.4 and Resharper set to Latest Version.